# coldfusion 8 server startup issue

Tags: coldfusion

I'm getting this error on coldfusion 8 server startup, most things seem to work, but certain pages throw a 500 error. I've no idea what is causing this or how to fix.

Has anyone seen this before? [coldfuison_8 linux Centos5]

UPDATE - I've done some tinkering and found a directory full of what look like compliled class files: /opt/coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfclasses seems to contain all the compiled java classes & is persistent from one restart to another.

If I delete the contents of this directory everything is fine, no more errors on startup. SO:
- it seems that maybe one or more of these files is going corrupt and causing the 500 issue?  When I went to delete the files there were actually more than the server could delete [argument list too long] - I had to whack the whole directory & recreate it.

Any thoughts/ideas on why or how these files are going bad [assumption] & how to prevent it in the future?

-thanks
-sean

```
service coldfusion_8 start
Starting ColdFusion 8...
The ColdFusion 8 server is starting up and will be available shortly.
======================================================================
Running the ColdFusion 8 connector wizard
======================================================================
Configuring the web server connector (Launched on the first run of the ColdFusion 8 start script)
Running apache connector wizard...
*** glibc detected *** /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/bin/java: free(): invalid pointer: 0xb7e4e290 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0xb7eddaa6]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x90)[0xb7ee0fc0]
/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so[0x6602f93]
/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so[0x65b3fe0]
/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so[0x65b5c1d]
/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so[0x65b9099]
/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so(JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x53)[0x639c293]
/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/bin/java[0x804afcc]
/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/bin/java(JavaMain+0x72)[0x8049942]
/lib/libpthread.so.0[0xb7fc945b]
/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb7f4524e]
======= Memory map: ========
06000000-0665c000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 86672232   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so
0665c000-066a0000 rwxp 0065c000 00:59 86672232   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so
066a0000-06ac2000 rwxp 066a0000 00:00 0
08048000-08052000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 86638734   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/bin/java
08052000-08053000 rwxp 00009000 00:59 86638734   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/bin/java
08053000-08074000 rwxp 08053000 00:00 0
80300000-80321000 rwxp 80300000 00:00 0
80321000-80400000 --xp 80321000 00:00 0
804aa000-804b5000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 25170338   /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20070626.so.1
804b5000-804b6000 rwxp 0000a000 00:59 25170338   /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20070626.so.1
b4cbf000-b4cc8000 rwxp b4cbf000 00:00 0
b4cc8000-b4d7f000 rwxp b4cc8000 00:00 0
b4d7f000-b4fbf000 rwxp b4d7f000 00:00 0
b4fbf000-b7d7f000 rwxp b4fbf000 00:00 0
b7d7f000-b7d8e000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 86672238   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/libzip.so
b7d8e000-b7d90000 rwxp 0000e000 00:59 86672238   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/libzip.so
b7d90000-b7db3000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 86672272   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so
b7db3000-b7db5000 rwxp 00023000 00:59 86672272   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so
b7db5000-b7dc0000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 86672264   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/libverify.so
b7dc0000-b7dc1000 rwxp 0000b000 00:59 86672264   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/libverify.so
b7dc1000-b7dca000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 25170318   /lib/libnss_files-2.5.so
b7dca000-b7dcb000 r-xp 00008000 00:59 25170318   /lib/libnss_files-2.5.so
b7dcb000-b7dcc000 rwxp 00009000 00:59 25170318   /lib/libnss_files-2.5.so
b7dcc000-b7ddf000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 25170304   /lib/libnsl-2.5.so
b7ddf000-b7de0000 r-xp 00012000 00:59 25170304   /lib/libnsl-2.5.so
b7de0000-b7de1000 rwxp 00013000 00:59 25170304   /lib/libnsl-2.5.so
b7de1000-b7de3000 rwxp b7de1000 00:00 0
b7de4000-b7dec000 rwxs 00000000 68:05 48545826   (deleted) /tmp/hsperfdata_root/23911
b7dec000-b7df3000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 25170246   /lib/librt-2.5.so
b7df3000-b7df4000 r-xp 00006000 00:59 25170246   /lib/librt-2.5.so
b7df4000-b7df5000 rwxp 00007000 00:59 25170246   /lib/librt-2.5.so
b7df5000-b7dfb000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 86672314   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/native_threads/libhpi.so
b7dfb000-b7dfc000 rwxp 00006000 00:59 86672314   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/native_threads/libhpi.so
b7dfc000-b7dfd000 rwxp b7dfc000 00:00 0
b7dfd000-b7dfe000 r-xp b7dfd000 00:00 0
b7dfe000-b7e01000 --xp b7dfe000 00:00 0
b7e01000-b7e4f000 rwxp b7e01000 00:00 0
b7e4f000-b7e74000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 25170336   /lib/libm-2.5.so
b7e74000-b7e75000 r-xp 00024000 00:59 25170336   /lib/libm-2.5.so
b7e75000-b7e76000 rwxp 00025000 00:59 25170336   /lib/libm-2.5.so
b7e76000-b7e77000 rwxp b7e76000 00:00 0
b7e77000-b7fb1000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 25170592   /lib/libc-2.5.so
b7fb1000-b7fb3000 r-xp 0013a000 00:59 25170592   /lib/libc-2.5.so
b7fb3000-b7fb4000 rwxp 0013c000 00:59 25170592   /lib/libc-2.5.so
b7fb4000-b7fb7000 rwxp b7fb4000 00:00 0
b7fb7000-b7fb9000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 25170292   /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b7fb9000-b7fba000 r-xp 00001000 00:59 25170292   /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b7fba000-b7fbb000 rwxp 00002000 00:59 25170292   /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b7fbb000-b7fc2000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 86672248   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so
b7fc2000-b7fc4000 rwxp 00006000 00:59 86672248   /opt/coldfusion8/runtime/jre/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so
b7fc4000-b7fd7000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 25170430   /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b7fd7000-b7fd8000 r-xp 00012000 00:59 25170430   /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b7fd8000-b7fd9000 rwxp 00013000 00:59 25170430   /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b7fd9000-b7fdb000 rwxp b7fd9000 00:00 0
b7fe4000-b7fe5000 rwxp b7fe4000 00:00 0
b7fe5000-b7ffe000 r-xp 00000000 00:59 25170244   /lib/ld-2.5.so
b7ffe000-b7fff000 r-xp 00019000 00:59 25170244   /lib/ld-2.5.so
b7fff000-b8000000 rwxp 0001a000 00:59 25170244   /lib/ld-2.5.so
bffca000-bfffe000 rwxp bffc9000 00:00 0
ffffe000-fffff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
/opt/coldfusion8/bin/cf-connectors.sh: line 68: 23911 Aborted                 $CONNECTOR_JAVA -Dtrace.ci=1 -jar $CF_DIR/runtime/lib/wsconfig.jar -server coldfusion -ws apache -dir /etc/httpd/conf -bin /usr/sbin/httpd -script /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd -ws32 -coldfusion -v >/opt/coldfusion8/ConnectorInstall0.txt 2>&1
=======================================
There was an error while running the connector wizard
Connector installation was not successful
=======================================
======================================================================
ColdFusion 8 has been started.
ColdFusion 8 will write logs to /opt/coldfusion8/logs/cfserver.log
======================================================================
```

Here are the Java args...

```
java.args=-server  -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.manager "-Djava.security.policy=/opt/coldfusion8/lib/coldfusion.policy" "-Djava.security.auth.policy=/opt/coldfusion8/lib/neo_jaas.policy" -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home}/../ -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/../lib -Dcoldfusion.classPath={application.home}/../lib/updates,{application.home}/../lib,{application.home}/../gateway/lib/,{application.home}/../wwwroot/WEB-INF/flex/jars,{application.home}/../wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfform/jars
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Have you made any modifications to the java args? Did you restore settings from another server onto this one? Has this ever worked for you or is it directly after install that it fails?

Comment: What user account is the service running under?

Comment: @Dan - the server has been running with that config for about 3 years... this issue came up once, but went away after a couple restarts.
@Sean - coldfusion is running under apache

Answer (score 0):

When a CFML template is called, it is compiled by the server into a class file. Normally, this is held in memory.

In the ColdFusion Administrator, you have the option to change this to "Save Class Files" (Settings). This is typically a setting used in production environments.

The directory you specified, /opt/coldfusion8/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfclasses, is the directory that ColdFusion saves these files to.

Go back to CF Admin, uncheck "Save Class Files", delete the contents of that folder, and re-start the server. You can now begin to accurately troubleshoot where your problematic code truly lies...and fix it, without the CF Server compiling and saving those erroneous CF templates to disk.

Answer (score 0):

It is very wierd that the issue came up after so many years. However the connector script is only run when the CF server is started for the first time. There might have happened some glitch which made it run again.

I got the issue on my instaallation/startup of CF10.

I think you need to check this link which saved me last few hairs left on my head:http://www.stillnetstudios.com/problems-installing-the-coldfusion-connector-on-linuxapache/